# Find monotony of $f(x)=x^5 +x^4 -11x^3 + 9x^2$

Tags: calculus, functions

How can I find the monotony of $f(x)=x^5 +x^4 -11x^3 + 9x^2$ ? Derivative doesnt help much. Is there any other approach ?

Comment: What's the reason why you think the derivative doesn't help?

Comment: @namsap because it isnt easy to find roots for derivative

Comment: Findung roots of the derivative ends up in finding roots of a polynomial of degree 3. And this is easy since these are always solvable using radicals, i.e. there are formulas.